# DOMDocument::loadXML(): Argument #1 ($source) must not be empty in DomMerger.php

Tags: magento2, grid, xml

Keep getting this error in exception, no solutions to find on the internet:

**DOMDocument::loadXML(): Argument #1 ($source) must not be empty in /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/DomMerger.php:32**

I have seen some solution that says to remove empty file or remove space in XML file, but I don't seen any empty file,

This happened since I updated magento -> 2.4.5

So how to know which xml file it is

Thank You Harish

Answer (score 1):

Try this all steps

The error you're encountering indicates an issue with an empty source argument being passed to the **loadXML**() method of the **DOMDocument** class in the **DomMerger.php** file. This error is likely occurring during the XML parsing process in Magento after the update to version 2.4.5.

```
To identify the XML file causing the error, you can enable Magento's developer mode and configure it to display detailed error messages
```

1.Access your Magento installation via SSH or FTP.

2.Locate the **index.php** file in the root directory of your Magento installation.

3.Open the **index.php** file in a text editor.

4.Look for the following line:

```
  #ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

5.After uncommenting the line, add the following code.

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

6.Save the changes to the **index.php** file.

Now, when you visit your Magento store, you should see a detailed error message that includes the XML file causing the issue. The error message will display the file path along with the line number where the error occurs

Answer (score 1):

> I fixed that issue by remove spacing at start of the xml file.

Comment: how you get that xml file?

Comment: Linux command for the file :-

find /path/to/dest -type f -empty

Comment: Seems like this cmd use for find empty file not for finding spacing, right?

Comment: Right, It is for empty