DOMDocument::loadXML(): Argument #1 ($source) must not be empty
My exception log in magento 2.4.7-p3 if full of:
main.CRITICAL: ValueError: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Argument #1 ($source) must not be empty in /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/DomMerger.php:322

I understand that in an xml file there is space at first line.
So I tried with:
find my/path/ -type f -empty

like adviced in this question
but it is not returning any xml files. I see txt files, csv, php, md
Am I missing something please?

Question with similar title https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/367365/

It seems there's an issue with HTML entity support for certain special characters. To fix this, you need to replace the named entities with their corresponding numeric codes.
Please check the log files, open the relevant file, and insert the line below before the error line. Use the appropriate HTML named entity and replace it with its numeric code.
Here's an example:
$result = str_replace('&reg;', '&#174;', $result);
Make sure to adjust the code to match the specific characters you're working with. Let me know if you need any more guidance!

Will check and update

Mathod 1: By Enable DEVELOPER mode. It will be show layout file name.
Method 2: Debug in vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(790)
Method 3 : Debug layout file processing by print final merge layout xml. Reference https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10533
